# Ship maven dependencies across machines

Tags: java, maven

I have some bunch of maven dependencies(around 20+ jars) installed in my development machine in default (~/.m2) directory. I want all those dependencies to be available in an already existing dependency folder (say mvn_d) in my server.

How to deploy new handful from my local dev machine to server running code? I have two routes in mind. Both with some limitations, could somebody recommend better.

1. Tar all dependencies and scp, then go to the server and untar place accordingly. Because of the current setup, I have to do chown and all the work and I found it little dirty for me.
2. Get pom file there and download using maven. Again it will download in its own structures making subfolders, so again I need to copy all jars to my required folder.

In both the cases developer is handling the shipping. I believe there should be a better way in a tool as accomplished and widely used as maven. Note that I don't want to make my deployed jar fatter by adding all dependencies embedded in the snapshot jar. I want them in the directory dedicated for the jars in my server.

**EDIT:** So many good answers, but I could choose only. I will look into Artifactory to solve this issue for all.

Comment: If possible you could make that server a remote repository allowing maven to deploy to that remote repository (`mvn install` will "install" the resulting artefact in your local Maven repository - the ".m2"-folder, `mvn deploy` will attempt to deploy the same artefact to a defined remote repository - which you can configure (i unfortunately never did it myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Maven Deploy](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html) command to deploy your jars to the remote repository (one by one).

Command format:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId= \
  -DartifactId= \
  -Dversion= \
  -Dpackaging= \
  -Dfile= \
  -DrepositoryId= \
  -Durl=
```

Else if you are using Nexus or Artifactory, if you have admin rights then you can upload them manually via the web page.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to start using a repository manager and all your problems are solved. Either Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have a look at the Maven dependency plugin.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html